# Owen's T function in Excel

Tags: excel, statistics

For context, I was trying to find a way to set the skewness of a distribution, leading me to the [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) which uses [Owen's T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function)  in its cumulative distribution function. After searching up for a bit, my understanding was that Excel does not provide it.

While I did realize afterwards that there are simpler solution available for my specific problem (including [WEIBULL.DIST](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weibull-dist-function-4e783c39-9325-49be-bbc9-a83ef82b45db), [LOGNORM.DIST.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/lognorm-dist-function-eb60d00b-48a9-4217-be2b-6074aee6b070)..) by that point I already had a working prototype.

See my answer below for my current implementation. I'll be happy to know if I have been blind-sided in my search for an existing Excel implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full function uses Excel 365 [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) and can be loaded into [Excel name register](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4), as described in the former documentation link (Step 3).

The implementation is based on *Patefield, M. and Tandy, D. (2000) "Fast and accurate Calculation of Owen’s T-Function", Journal of Statistical Software, 5*, although I mostly relied on this [Github thread](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsFuns.jl/issues/99#issuecomment-900802603) which was easier for me to process. I did some quick verification using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%3Dowent%280.9999993%2C0.99%29) but no extensive test.

Other trivia:

- I failed to make use of the IFS function [[Link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/ifs-evaluates-all-elements/m-p/3200131)],
- I did some check for the n=48 as to not blindly follow the julia's implementation [[Link](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/legendre-gauss.html#n48)],
- I attempted to use a spilled array for the "h" argument but when it did not work I decided that it was enough.

```
=LAMBDA(h,a,
LET(
helper_owen_t,LAMBDA(hh,aa,
LET(x,{0.998771007252426,-0.99353017226635,-0.984124583722826,-0.970591592546247,-0.95298770316043,-0.931386690706554,-0.905879136715569,-0.876572020274247,-0.843588261624393,-0.807066204029442,-0.76715903251574,-0.724034130923814,-0.677872379632663,-0.628867396776513,-0.577224726083972,-0.523160974722233,-0.466902904750958,-0.408686481990716,-0.34875588629216,-0.287362487355455,-0.224763790394689,-0.161222356068891,-0.0970046992094627,-0.0323801709628693,0.0323801709628693,0.0970046992094627,0.161222356068891,0.224763790394689,0.287362487355455,0.34875588629216,0.408686481990716,0.466902904750958,0.523160974722233,0.577224726083972,0.628867396776513,0.677872379632663,0.724034130923814,0.76715903251574,0.807066204029442,0.843588261624393,0.876572020274247,0.905879136715569,0.931386690706554,0.95298770316043,0.970591592546247,0.984124583722826,0.99353017226635,0.998771007252426},
w,{0.00315334605230591,0.00732755390127628,0.0114772345792346,0.0155793157229438,0.0196161604573556,0.0235707608393243,0.0274265097083569,0.031167227832798,0.0347772225647705,0.0382413510658307,0.0415450829434646,0.0446745608566943,0.0476166584924904,0.0503590355538544,0.0528901894851936,0.0551995036999841,0.0572772921004032,0.0591148396983956,0.0607044391658938,0.0620394231598926,0.063114192286254,0.0639242385846481,0.0644661644359499,0.0647376968126838,0.0647376968126838,0.0644661644359499,0.0639242385846481,0.063114192286254,0.0620394231598926,0.0607044391658938,0.0591148396983956,0.0572772921004032,0.0551995036999841,0.0528901894851936,0.0503590355538544,0.0476166584924904,0.0446745608566943,0.0415450829434646,0.0382413510658307,0.0347772225647705,0.031167227832798,0.0274265097083569,0.0235707608393243,0.0196161604573556,0.0155793157229438,0.0114772345792346,0.00732755390127628,0.00315334605230591},
SUMPRODUCT(w,1/(2*PI())*(aa/2)*EXP(-0.5*(hh^2)*(1+(aa*x)^2))/(1+(aa*x)^2)))),
cdf,LAMBDA(lvar,NORM.DIST(lvar,0,1,TRUE)),
t_owen,LAMBDA(ME,h,a,
IF(h<0,ME(ME,-h,a),
IF(h=0,ATAN(a)/(2*PI()),
IF(a<0,ME(ME,h,-a),
IF(a=0,0,
IF(a=1,1/2*cdf(h)*(1-cdf(h)),
IF(a>1,(cdf(h)+cdf(a*h))/2-cdf(h)*cdf(a*h)-ME(ME,a*h,1/a),
IF(a>0.999999,0.5*cdf(h)*(1-cdf(h))-1/(2*PI())/ATAN((1-a)/(1+a))*EXP(-0.5*(1-a)*h^2*ATAN((1-a)/(1+a))),
helper_owen_t(h,a))))))))),t_owen(t_owen,h,a)))(H1,$A$1)
```